# Lock screen with out Thread.sleep or giving some amount of time in jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

Hi all I am having a requirement where I have to show loading image when I perform any operation. I have gone through several blogs and articles, but all of them are doing some thing like giving some amount of time in Jquery or the scripts used, or using `Thread.Sleep` method.

Is it possible to do with out these two. Means I don't know how much time it takes to load a page, until and unless the page get loaded I would like to show the waiting screen for the user.

Comment: If you saw `Thread.Sleep` in a blog describing how to show 'Loading page', then it was just to defer response so you can notice how it works..

Comment: From your question it sounds like you need to call JavaScript function to display a loading image, then when your operation is complete call another JavaScript function to hide it.  Like @MichalKlouda points out the `Thread.Sleep()` is probably just there to create an artificial pause to simulate your operation.

Comment: Even in javascript function they are calling some time like `setTimeout(function(){
    $("#blocker").hide();
}, 2000);
​`

Comment: @User that's just to show the blocker for two seconds. You can use any other event (ajax finished) to hide the blocker.

Comment: `Michal` so as per your comment irrespective of the time we have given in `thread.sleep` the page will get loaded only after the whole operation is completed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can display the loading image when you start some action and remove it when you finish the action:

```
$("#loading-image").show();
pendingActions ++;
$.get({...,success:function(){
  pendingActions --;
  if(!pendingActions){
    $("#loading-image").hide()
  }
}});
```

Comment: Assume I have some DB operations to be done on the page, how can I use your code as per my requirement

Comment: @The ajax call will finish when the server is finished responding (+ network delay). The server responds when it has finished updating the database.

Comment: Can you give some sample demo that how can I implement as per you said in a real time scenario and any links that can be helpful to me

Comment: So: client shows the loading image, then sends a request > server receives the request and issues a database action > the database does its job > server call to the database returns > server creates a response, sends it and finishes > client waits for the full response, then triggers the `success` handler > the success handler clears the loading image.

Comment: Database actions happen on the server. The client only waits for the response. I assume you know how to query the database from your server.

Comment: Yeah I know the database operations and all but I am confused how to implement the scenario i required as per ur code

Comment: Well, I have given you the client code and the server doesn't do anything special.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19155/discussion-between-user-and-jan-dvorak)

Comment: Or, you mean "while the main page loads", not "while I perform a javascript operation"?

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
$(document).load(function() { 

});
```

from the jQuery library. It waits until all web content has been loaded, and then executes the code within the function. I would build the page, and display a waiting screen wherever in the html where you need it, and then once all content(including images) has been loaded, I can use java script to remove the waiting screens from the html `$('.Screen').hide();`
That way the user doesn't see the process of each image popping up one at a time, intead sees waiting screens, and then suddenly they're all gone and the images are visible.